# $http.get('{{ path(" error en el path

Tags: angularjs

Hola soy nuevo usando `AngularJs` y no puedo puedo pasar variables a php Silex, si las cacha pero cuando hago la función no las toma la ruta

lanza este error:

> http://localhost/prueba/web/prueba/%7B%7B%20path(%22admin.filtro%22)%20%7D%7D?apm=perez&app=hernandez&nombre=juan

y cuando lo hago directo con un action

> http://localhost/prueba/web/prueba/filtro?nombre=juan&app=hernandez&apm=perez&folioRegistro=&id=&edad=

pero no lo quiero así por que lo cachar en un json

```
function buscar() {
        $http.get('{{ path("admin.filtro") }}', { params: vm.filtro })
            .success(function(data) {
                if (data.status == "success") {
                    vm.registros = data.registros;
                }
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $http.get('{{ path("admin.filtro") }}', { params: vm.filtro })
```

eso que estas poniendo  **{{path("admin.filtro")}}** se utiliza en las vistas para que AngularJs cuando muestre el fichero cambie todo lo que esta  dentro de **{{ }}** y lo sustituya por el valor correspondiente que viene a ser en este caso $scope.path= (que tengas en el controlador)

Deberia ser algo como: 
    $http.get(vm.path("admin.filtro") , { params: vm.filtro })

o si path es una factoria/servicio

```
$http.get(path("admin.filtro") , { params: vm.filtro })
```

Comment: No lo habia aplicado bien, excelente solucion gracias.